# ListPointPlot3D vs ListPlot3D (ListPlot3D not working for data)

Tags: plotting

I want to use the function ListPlot3D to visualize data contained in a number of matrices. The matrices are all (191,3) in size- each matrix representing a measurement taken along a direction at a different time. I've included a sample of the first 20 points in two of these matrices below as "a" and "b" (apologies for odd formatting).

```
a = {{0.20242, 6244, 0.722142}, {0.21284, 6244, 0.713891}, {0.22328, 6244, 0.704955}, {0.23369, 6244, 0.697195}, {0.2441, 6244, 0.687987}, {0.25454, 6244, 0.679169}, {0.26495, 6244, 0.669641}, {0.27538, 6244, 0.660857}, {0.28579, 6244, 0.652068}, {0.29622, 6244, 0.643073}, {0.30662, 6244, 0.634506}, {0.31703, 6244, 0.62691}, {0.32746, 6244, 0.622205}, {0.33785, 6244, 0.617918}, {0.34828, 6244, 0.614794}, {0.35868, 6244, 0.613043}, {0.3691, 6244, 0.614047}, {0.3795, 6244, 0.613577}, {0.38989, 6244, 0.613514}, {0.4003, 6244, 0.611439}}

b = {{0.20242, 12488, 0.732877}, {0.21284, 12488, 0.72343}, {0.22328, 12488, 0.713726}, {0.23369, 12488, 0.705098}, {0.2441, 12488, 0.697295}, {0.25454, 12488, 0.693061}, {0.26495, 12488, 0.692608}, {0.27538, 12488, 0.691477}, {0.28579, 12488, 0.688314}, {0.29622, 12488, 0.683847}, {0.30662, 12488, 0.674824}, {0.31703, 12488, 0.663353}, {0.32746, 12488, 0.650306}, {0.33785, 12488, 0.636811}, {0.34828, 12488, 0.631822}, {0.35868, 12488, 0.635797}, {0.3691, 12488, 0.642863}, {0.3795, 12488, 0.647861}, {0.38989, 12488, 0.648684}, {0.4003, 12488, 0.643717}}
```

There's no trouble plotting them using the following expression:

```
Plot1 = ListPointPlot3D[{a, b}]
```

But there's only a blank set of axes showing if the following expression is used:

```
Plot2 = ListPlot3D[{a, b}]
```

Is there something I can do to re-scale/etc data so that it can be displayed this way? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: what kind of plot do you want? Why is the output `ListPointPlot3D` not suitable for you?

Comment: I'm trying to very explicitly show the change in the data over time rather than just have multiple traces on a single plot so I'd prefer the type of "surface" with the tie lines that ListPlot3D provides- if there's another plot style that similarly provides this surface effect and works with the data provided that would also be fine.

Comment: `ListPlot3D` wants the input points to not have a fixed value of some coordinates. It may be easier to make a custom visualization with `Graphics3D` in this case. Are the first elements of the points in the two lists corresponding to one another, like it seems to be the case in the data you provided?

Comment: @glS, this is correct- the different data traces are all measured at the same points so the first elements of each matrix are the same (i.e. if only the first elements were made into a list it would always have the same values).

Answer (score 2):

If the data has the structure you show you may use a custom "ladder" representation to better see the increase of the points:

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize@0.02]],
 Graphics3D[{
   Table[
    {
     Polygon[{a[[k]], a[[k + 1]], b[[k + 1]], b[[k]]}]
     },
    {k, Range[Length@a - 1]}
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting solution- I'd like to get as close as possible to something like [this](http://tinypic.com/r/168x54l/9)

Comment: @tka can you provide a dataset like that for testing?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think the suggestion of @Edmund is a bit easier for me to work with the but customization your answer offers will be very useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the *data* surface syntax of [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) along with the [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) option.

```
Plot2 = ListPlot3D[{a[[All, -1]], b[[All, -1]]},
  DataRange -> {MinMax[a[[All, 1]]], MinMax[Join[a[[All, 2]], b[[All, 2]]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Edmund , this works really well for me and it gave me some insight into why ListPlot3D was having so many issues with the format I'm using.